# Portfolio template: display number of posts based on the day of the week?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is post two for me here, so my apologies if I leave something out!  I'm also pretty weak at wordpress coding, but I'm learning!

I'm using a portfolio template to organizes pages of educational content.  Each page has 5 posts, one for each weekday (Mon-Fri).  I'll have different groups accessing different pages each week, but most of the pages will be "old".  So, when visiting them now, you see all 5 days at once.

I want them to only see the previous and current days posts.  So, visiting on Monday, you see only Monday's post, even though Monday-Friday is published.  Visiting on Wednesday you see Mon-Wed.

All of the pages are the same, there will only ever be 5 posts.  This method doesn't have much flexibility, but that's ok.  I'll likely include a meta checkbox to "enable/disable" this functionality, but won't need to use that much.

Here's a link to the current template-portfolio.php:  https://gist.github.com/4671326

And here's the one I tried to modify:  https://gist.github.com/4661867

Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
$days = array(
              'monday' => 1,
              'tuesday' => 2,
              'wednesday' => 3,
              'thursday' => 4,
              'friday' => 5,
              );

$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'portfolio',
              'orderby' => 'menu_order',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'meta_value' => esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portsort', true ) ),
              'posts_per_page' => $days[date( 'l', current_time('timestamp') )],
              );
```

My additions aren't working.  Here's the logic I was trying to put in there:

> Show #number# of posts depending on what day it is.  So, if the date returns Thursday, then just show 4 posts.

To me, that seems like it would be easy to do... but it's not working right for some reason.

SO... my questions:

1. Is this the appropriate coding logic for this to work smoothly?
2. What have I done incorrectly in the code itself?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1, your Q's are very good, no need to apologize, as a matter of fact it's [considered noise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/185667) here in the Stack ;) :::: You'll probably not aware of [wordpress.se], lot's of WP experts over there. But please, don't duplicate your Q's, [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667) beforehand, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Older question but might simply be a an issue of case sensitivity:

```
$days = array(
          'monday' => 1,
          'tuesday' => 2,
          'wednesday' => 3,
          'thursday' => 4,
          'friday' => 5,
          );

$current_day = strtolower( date( 'l', current_time('timestamp') ) );

$args = array(
          'post_type' => 'portfolio',
          'orderby' => 'menu_order',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'meta_value' => esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portsort', true ) ),
          'posts_per_page' => $days[$current_day],
          );
```